# Mute button does not work when I switch the scenes

Tags: unity-game-engine

AudioManager and sound effects are working just fine at the beginning of scene, however it does not work when i switch the scenes. Or even with the same scene.

I would be grateful if you could help with that and PlayerPrefs issue. I have been searching all around the forum about PlayerPrefs but i could not be sure about what to type.

Thank you very much.

```
  using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Audio;
using System;


public class AudioManager : MonoBehaviour {

    bool mutebutton = false;

    public Sound[] sounds;
    public static AudioManager instance;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Awake () {

        if (instance == null)
            instance = this;
        else
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            return;

        }

        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);

        foreach (Sound s in sounds)
        {
            s.source = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
            s.source.clip = s.clip;
            s.source.volume = s.volume;

        }
    }

   void Start()
    {
        Play("Theme");
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("volume", AudioListener.volume);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    public void Play (string name)
    {
        Sound s = Array.Find(sounds, sound => sound.name == name);
        s.source.Play();
    }

    public void Mute()
    {
        if (!mutebutton)
        {
            mutebutton = true;
            AudioListener.volume = 0;

        }
        else
        {
            mutebutton = false;
            AudioListener.volume = 1;

        }

}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only miss `"Theme"` sound on scene load:
`Start()` method won't be called again on scene load. 
You have to actively call `Play("Theme")` after loading a scene.

Comment: And how may I do that ?

Comment: Because you have used a SIngletone pattern, you can access the AudioManager from everywhere else in Code. By using `AudioManager.instance.Play("Theme");` in the StartMethod of a Script existing only in the scene you load you can play it. Or you use a Script for Scene Loading which also ueses DontDestroyOnLoad. Then you can put this line where you load the level.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer.

I have added AudioManager.instance.Play("Theme"); as you have said to void Start method instead of Play("Theme"). However, still when my game object get destroyed and restart the scene, i cannot use the button. Nothing happens :/

Comment: You need another simple Script in every scene which will Start the Music. Make a new one with the Start method which calls Play and put it in every scene you want to load. Don t put it in the AudioManager! The AudioManager is consistent over scenes and his Start will be called only once at the beginning of your game because the DontDestroyOnLoad. A better place would be a consistent SceneLoader Script to handle Scenes and audio!

Comment: Possibility 1: Script on one GameObject **in every scene**: `public class StartAudio : MonoBehaviour { void Start(){AudioManager.instance.Play("Theme"); }}`

Comment: Possibility 2: Make the Script where you load the levels also a Singleton and use DontDestroyOnLoad to handle the audio on Scene Load there.

Comment: thank you very much for your comment. but when i try the first possibility on every scene, the music is beginning from zero.

my problem is, the mute button is invalid on main menu right after we change the scene.

Comment: So you want to play the "theme" ongioing even if a new level was loaded?

Comment: The AudioListner is normally on the Main Camera. Remove it from there and put one on your AudioManager-GameObject. Otherwise every scene has a new AudioListner because there is a cam is in the scene. You have to remove the AudiListner from every camera in every scene.